# Execute 2 queries that are in 2 variables and store the result in other 2 variables

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-sql, database-cursor

As mentioned in the question, I want to store the results of these queries into other variables so that I can compare the output and find the ones which are not matching. Please help me out with it. The variable @Stagename consists of the first query and variable @correctname consists of the second query. I found some answers of storing them into a table variable but it is not working. These queries are not a single query and hence are stored in the form of rows of a table and are being fetched by the cursor. I've passed the second variable @tablename which I want as the final output but only of the ones in whom the comparison is not matching. I've used the following code:

```
DECLARE @Stagename VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @correctname VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @tablename  VARCHAR(MAX)
--DECLARE @StageCount  VARCHAR(max)
--DECLARE @IndexCount  VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE (StageCount Varchar(max), TableName VARCHAR(MAX))
DECLARE @Table2 TABLE (IndexCount Varchar(max), TableName VARCHAR(MAX))


--DEALLOCATE IF EXISTS CS_StagingIndex
DECLARE CS_StagingIndex CURSOR FOR  
SELECT StageCount, CorrectCount, TableName FROM bak.StagingindexesQuery

OPEN CS_StagingIndex
FETCH NEXT FROM CS_StagingIndex
INTO @Stagename,@Correctname,@tablename

WHILE @@Fetch_Status = 0

BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @Table1(StageCount,TableName) VALUES (exec(@StageName),@tablename);
    INSERT INTO @Table2(IndexCount,TableName) VALUES (exec(@CorrectName),@tablename);
    --Select * from @Table1 Ignore this.
FETCH NEXT FROM CS_StagingIndex
INTO @Stagename,@Correctname,@tablename

END
CLOSE CS_StagingIndex
DEALLOCATE CS_StagingCursor
```

**Select count(1) from stg.LogisticsElectronicAddres** - This is the query stored in @StageName.
**select count(1) from (select distinct recid1 from stg.LogisticsElectronicAddress) x** - This is the query stored in @IndexName.

**LogisticsElectronicAddress** and this is the tablename.
Now if for example, the result of StageName query is 2000 and the result of Correctname is also 2000, then the tablename should not be printed. But if the results dont match, then I want the tablename to be printed. There are multiple rows in **bak.StagingIndexesQuery** table that contain such queries for multiple tables.

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server. The query of yours does not look like using MySQL syntax; so I have removed those tags.

Comment: please provide some sample data and the expected result

Comment: please update the question with the added information. It is hard to read in the comment

Comment: @squirrel I hope now its alright???

Comment: what you are doing here is not advisable. It is subject to injection attack

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that's the correct EXEC syntax for sql-server; I don't think that is going to work.

What you can do is use the statement .. INSERT table EXEC storedprocName.

However, there are constraints - the table layout must match that of the return procedure in terms of column count/order/data types/length ( within reason, ie if a column in the table is NVARCHAR(100) and the stored procedure returns that column as NVARCHAR(105), that should be fine - unless of course the data itself exceeds the 100 length). I believe column names are ignored for INSERT/EXEC

Also, if the query being executed has an INSERT/EXEC , this will not work (only one allowed at anyone time)

So you will need to use dynamic SQL...

```
DECLARE @MySQLStatement NVARCHAR(400)
DECLARE @MyStoedProcName NVARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE (StageCount Varchar(max), TableName VARCHAR(MAX))
SET @MySQLStatement = 'INSERT @Tablename EXEC ' + @StoredProcedure
EXEC sp_ExecuteSQL @MySQLStatement
```

Now off the top of my head, I can't remember if that @Table1 will be in the scope of that dynamic SQL statement. If it isn't, make @Table1 a temp table (ie create table #table1 [ ... etc ]  )